# Downloading and then uploading files with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, upload, download

Now first of all, I'm making a UserScript, meaning that I don't own the servers from which I download files or the servers to which I upload files.

So I need to download a file from a server (needs to be any type, not just text files), and then somehow submit that file to a file upload form on another website. Is that possible? At first I was wondering if I'd be able to submit the file directly from one server to the other, but I don't think that's possible.

So is there any way I can do this? I can use jQuery as well.

Comment: Here I found some thread about how do the uploading part: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690086/uploading-file-from-one-server-to-another-via-http-post

Answer (score 2):

As long as you won't be blocked by XSS prevention, load the data using an XMLHttpRequest then post it to the other site.

Here is a very basic functional example:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("get", "http://www.example.com/file", true);
xhr.onload = function () {
  xhr.close();
  var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr2.open("post", "http://www.example2.com/form", true);
  xhr2.send(xhr.response);
}
xhr.send();
```

I would advise that you add some code to catch errors

For more details on XMLHttpRequests, the documentation can be found on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), with instructions on how to use it on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)